# how to style motion icon in styled-component in React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, framer-motion

Is it possible to style motion(framer-motion) icon in styled-components in React.
Here is my style.js file:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { FaRegMoon } from "react-icons/fa";

export const MoonStyled = styled(motion.FaRegMoon)`
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  font-size: 40px;
`;
```

Here is my jsx file:

```
import {  SunStyled } from "./styles/styles";

<SunStyled/>
```

I tried making it `<motion.SunStyled/>` but it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to get it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the docs talk about this: https://www.framer.com/docs/component/#custom-components

This is the helpful statement that details how to forward a ref / make a custom component wrappable by motion:

```
const Component = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} />
))

const MotionComponent = motion(Component)
```

**The icon component doesn't [forward the ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to the actual dom svg, so that is why it is not wrappable by `motion`.**

```
 return (
      <svg
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="currentColor"
        strokeWidth="0"
        {...conf.attr}
        {...attr}
        {...svgProps}
        className={className}
        style={{ color: props.color || conf.color, ...conf.style, ...props.style}}
        height={computedSize}
        width={computedSize}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
      {title && <title>{title}</title>}
      {props.children}
    </svg>
    )
```

Even though they are spreading the props ref is the only prop that is not automatically passed.

[source link](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/blob/master/packages/react-icons/src/iconBase.tsx)

---

I wanted to test this on my own, so I made this example. It doesn't work for the above reason but feel free to see for yourself.

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-with-react-icons-rhqu6?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It would be a better question if you included the brief code to answer the question instead of just links.

Comment: You are right @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ. Added the code snippets for easier access!